# Undesired conditions hit when checking for list equality

Tags: c#, list

Currently facing a rather.. trivial issue.

I have two error-handling conditions:

`1.` Triggers `true` if two lists are inequal.

For example:

[image]

`2.` Triggers `true` if the `cachedList.Length` is `>` than the `newList.Length`.

For example:

[image]

First method to check string equality is this:

```
if (!checkEquality(cachedList, newList))
{
    // do something
}
```

Where `checkEquality()` is:

```
public bool checkEquality(List<string> cachedList, List<string> newList)
{
    if (cachedList.SequenceEqual(newList))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The second method I use is:

```
if (cachedList.Count > newList.Count)
{
    // Do something
}
```

With this said, and understandingly, when a scenario where condition no. 2 is hit, where the cached list is greater than the new list, both my conditions get hit. Both the "inequal" and "greater than" condition is hit, and it's causing undesired behavior in my code.

In order to not satisfy both these conditions when error-handling number 2 is hit, I need to think of an alternative to detect "inequality" in method number 1.

***EDIT:*** I decided to put in a condition to check if the counts of `newList` and `cachedList` are equal, and only check for their equality given their count is equal. Is this the right way to approach this?

```
public bool checkEquality(List<string> oldFirstList, List<string> newFirstList)
{
    if (oldFirstList.Count == newFirstList.Count)
    {
        if (oldFirstList.SequenceEqual(newFirstList))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I fail to see why you're using a `List<string>` to store numbers in the first place, instead of a `List<int>` or the like

Comment: You can directly return **oldFirstList.SequenceEqual(newFirstList)** for second test

Comment: I used `ints` to demonstrate this example.

Comment: Second, all your code can be reduced to `list1.Except(list2).Any()` which will return `true` if there's any item in `list1` that does not appear in `list2`.

Comment: Ah I see! Let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second problem it´s right the cachedList.Count > newList.Count, and that´s the reason why the if is true.

```
if (cachedList.Count > newList.Count)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This will "do something" because it´s true the condition

And your first problem, try something like this:

Instead of this:

```
if (!checkEquality(cachedList, newList))
{
   // do something
}
```

Try this directly:

```
if (cachedList.SequenceEqual(newList))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

This will return false;

Comment: Oscar do you mean getting rid of the method?

Comment: Yeah, I mean removing your own method, and only check this using the SequenceEqual. Why create a method that is already created? ;)

Comment: Oscar, I made it so that if the condition is `true`, to do nothing, and only do something if it's `false`. Is that OK? Like this: http://puu.sh/7cu3u/439033d222.png

Comment: In the if (cachedList.SequenceEqual(newList))?
If the sequence is equal, put your "do something", and if it´s false, or do nothing, or don´t put your else statement ;)

Comment: What I mean is -- is it OK to `do nothing` if the condition is true.

Comment: yeah, in this case you can do something like
if (cachedList.SequenceEqual(newList) == false)
//do something
and then forget about the else statement

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `SequenceEqual`, the length check is already being done there. Unless you have no other criteria other than length and equality, there is no need to wrap `SequenceEqual` into your own method. You can even define a type of `IEqualityComparer<T>` if you want to compare more than references.